# Tezos transactions life-time in mempool

Tags: node, mempool

Before a transactions get rejected from the mempool. What is the max of life-time of a transaction in the mempool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions should only live for 60 blocks within the mempool before being deleted. There have been reports in the bakers-slack of this not working correctly and some trx living for many thousands of blocks. The only way to clear your mempool is to restart your node.